# Better way to set no padding

Tags: flutter, performance, dart, optimization

There are 2 ways to display padding conditionally.

The first one is to pass `EdgeInsets.zero` to padding constructor like this:

```dart
Padding(
  padding: ... ? EdgeInsets.zero : ...,
  child: child,
)
```

The other way is to wrap the child conditionally like this:

```dart
if(...)
  Padding(padding: ..., child: child)
else child
```

Which one is better in terms of performance?

Comment: Not building a widget is always going to be more performant than building a no-op widget. That said, the difference is going to be largely negligible. Whichever approach you go with should instead depend on your specific project's needs and organization, not to mention which one looks the most right to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First one will be more efficient because you are not rebuilding entire widget, just changing its property